# filtering array of objects based on multiple selections

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects which looks like this

```
[
    {
        id: 101,
        name: 'Alex',
        tg: 'REV001',
        eng: 'IP'
    },
    {
        id: 102,
        name: 'Bob',
        tg: 'REV002',
        eng: 'CAD'
    },
    {
        id: 103,
        name: 'Carl',
        tg: 'REV001',
        eng: 'OPP'
    },
    {
        id: 104,
        name: 'Dave',
        tg: 'REV003',
        eng: 'IP'
    },
    {
        id: 105,
        name: 'Jeffry',
        tg: 'REV005',
        eng: 'OPP'
    },
]
```

I also have 3 select box which is like

```
// Name select
<select>
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option value="Alex">Alex</option>
  <option value="Bob">Bob</option>
  <option value="Carl">Carl</option>
  <option value="Dave">Dave</option>
  <option value="Jeffry">Jeffry</option>
</select>

// TG select
<select>
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option value="REV001">REV001</option>
  <option value="REV002">REV002</option>
  <option value="REV003">REV003</option>
  <option value="REV005">REV005</option>
</select>

// ENG select
<select>
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option value="IP">IP</option>
  <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
  <option value="OPP">OPP</option>
</select>
```

These select box shows all possible values present in array, categorized based on Name, TG and ENG.

I want to filter the data based on the selection of option from these select input.

For example,

If I have Name as all, ENG as all and TG as `REV001` then it should filter data array and get a new array with only objects having TG as `REV001`.

I already have events calls for value change, just want logic to how to filter data based on selected options. A function which should return a new array of filtered data from original data.

I tried to create a variable like

```
  filteredSearch: any = {
    NAME: 'All',
    ENG: 'All',
    TG: 'All'
  }
```

and wrote a method like

```
  onFilterSearch() {
    this.filteredList = [];
    this.requestData.forEach(element => {
      for (let key in this.filteredSearch) {
        if (!(this.filteredSearch[key] === '')) {
          if (element.header[key].includes(this.filteredSearch[key])) {
            this.filteredList.push(element);
          }
        } 
      }
    });
  }
```

I am changing `filteredSearch` as the select input get changed and calling the `onFilterSearch()`. But this didn't work for me, maybe I am missing something here.

Comment: Show us what you tried that didn't work. Stackoverflow isn't a free coding service. The objective here is for you to post the attempts you made to solve issue yourself and others help you fix your code

Comment: let me edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution could be made more robust by defining `currentFilter` as an object instead of an array (and by building the `<select>` elements in JavaScript from their respective lists to ensure that the HTML is never out of sync with the script), but it handles your use case as-is.

```js
// Defines globals
const lists = {
  name: "Alex,Bob,Carl,Dave,Jeffry".split(","),
  tg:   "REV001,REV002,REV003,REV004,REV005".split(","),
  eng:  "IP,CAD,OPP".split(",")
};
let data = [
    { id: 101, name: 'Alex',   tg: 'REV001', eng: 'IP'  },
    { id: 102, name: 'Bob',    tg: 'REV002', eng: 'CAD' },
    { id: 103, name: 'Carl',   tg: 'REV001', eng: 'OPP' },
    { id: 104, name: 'Dave',   tg: 'REV003', eng: 'IP'  },
    { id: 105, name: 'Jeffry', tg: 'REV005', eng: 'OPP' },
];
const dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("filterable");

// Runs the `filterData` function when the user changes something
document.addEventListener("change", filterData);

// Defines the `filterData` function
function filterData(event){

  // Converts the NodeList to an Array so we can use the `.includes`,
  //   `.map`, and `.filter` methods
  const dropdownArr = Array.from(dropdowns);

  // Makes sure the changed element was one we care about before proceeding
  if(dropdownArr.includes(event.target)){

    // Makes a new array from the selected values
    const currentFilter = dropdownArr.map(dropdownArr => dropdownArr.value);

    // Makes a new (filtered) array by applying each element of `currentFilter`
    //   to its respective property in each element of `data`
    //   (This is the fragile bit because it assumes the order is correct.)
    const output = data.filter(item =>
      (!currentFilter[0] || currentFilter[0] == item.name) &&
      (!currentFilter[1] || currentFilter[1] == item.tg) &&
      (!currentFilter[2] || currentFilter[2] == item.eng)
    );

    // Does something with the filtered data
    console.log(output.length > 0 ? output : "No matching results");
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="name" class="filterable">
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option value="Alex">Alex</option>
  <option value="Bob">Bob</option>
  <option value="Carl">Carl</option>
  <option value="Dave">Dave</option>
  <option value="Jeffry">Jeffry</option>
</select>
<select id="tg" class="filterable">
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option value="REV001">REV001</option>
  <option value="REV002">REV002</option>
  <option value="REV003">REV003</option>
  <option value="REV005">REV005</option>
</select>
<select id="eng" class="filterable">
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option value="IP">IP</option>
  <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
  <option value="OPP">OPP</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please find the logic and the code snippet below:

**Logic:**

```
var filteredData = data.filter(e => { 
  return (!nameSelect || e.name === nameSelect) && (!tgSelect || e.tg === tgSelect) && (!engSelect || e.eng === engSelect);
});
```

**Code Snippet:**

```html
// Name select
<select id="nameSelect">
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option value="Alex">Alex</option>
  <option value="Bob">Bob</option>
  <option value="Carl">Carl</option>
  <option value="Dave">Dave</option>
  <option value="Jeffry">Jeffry</option>
</select>
// TG select
<select id="tgSelect">
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option value="REV001">REV001</option>
  <option value="REV002">REV002</option>
  <option value="REV003">REV003</option>
  <option value="REV005">REV005</option>
</select>
// ENG select
<select id="engSelect">
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option value="IP">IP</option>
  <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
  <option value="OPP">OPP</option>
</select>
<br/>
<button id="filterBtn" type="button">Filter</button>
<script>
var data = [
    {
        id: 101,
        name: 'Alex',
        tg: 'REV001',
        eng: 'IP'
    },
    {
        id: 102,
        name: 'Bob',
        tg: 'REV002',
        eng: 'CAD'
    },
    {
        id: 103,
        name: 'Carl',
        tg: 'REV001',
        eng: 'OPP'
    },
    {
        id: 104,
        name: 'Dave',
        tg: 'REV003',
        eng: 'IP'
    },
    {
        id: 105,
        name: 'Jeffry',
        tg: 'REV005',
        eng: 'OPP'
    },
];

function filterData(data) {
  var nameSelect = document.getElementById("nameSelect");
  nameSelect = nameSelect.options[nameSelect.selectedIndex].value;
  var tgSelect = document.getElementById("tgSelect");
  tgSelect = tgSelect.options[tgSelect.selectedIndex].value;
  var engSelect = document.getElementById("engSelect");
  engSelect = engSelect.options[engSelect.selectedIndex].value;
  var filteredData = data.filter((e) => { 
    return (!nameSelect || e.name === nameSelect) && (!tgSelect || e.tg === tgSelect) && (!engSelect || e.eng === engSelect);
  });
  console.log(filteredData);
}

document.getElementById("filterBtn").addEventListener("click", e => {
  filterData(data);
});
</script>
```